# SpringBoot's @MultipartConfig maxFileSize not taking effect

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a controller with a `MultipartConfig` annotation (a snippet of which is show below):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("packages")
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 1024*1024*1024, maxRequestSize = 1024*1024*1024)
public class PackagesController
{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String create(@RequestParam("package") MultipartFile uploadedPackage)
    {
        // do stuff to the file
        return "create";
    }
}
```

When I upload a file to this endpoint, though, it appears to be using the default multipart config values:

```
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field package exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes.
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl$FileItemStreamImpl$1.raiseError(FileUploadBase.java:633) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.checkLimit(LimitedInputStream.java:76) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:98) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:68) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:293) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2776) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

My application looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Is there something I'm missing that allows the `@MultipartConfig` annotation to take effect?

Comment: I was able to get it working by using a separate AppConfig class with a MultipartConfigFactory method with a Bean annotation but I'm still not sure why it didn't work with the MultipartConfig annotation as above.

Comment: `@MultipartConfig` is a Servlet annotation. Spring MVC has no knowledge of it.

Comment: See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart) for how to enable multipart processing in standard Spring MVC. With Boot, it's a little different.

Comment: restarting tomcat (or other container) would work also.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you just want to control the multipart properties, you can use `multipart.max-file-size` and `multipart.max-request-size` properties. For example, you could raise the max size to `100Mb` by adding following piece of configurations in your `application.properties` file:

```
multipart.max-file-size=100MB
multipart.max-request-size=100MB
```

Values can use the suffixed `MB` or `KB` to indicate a *Megabyte* or *Kilobyte* size.

Under the hood, Spring Boot will create a `MultipartConfigElement` based on `MultipartProperties` and that `MultipartConfigElement` will be used in Servlet registration, as stated in [Spring MVC documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-multipart-resolver-standard). You can take a look at [`MultipartAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/MultipartAutoConfiguration.java) and [`DispatcherServletConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.java) and Checkout [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-multipart-file-upload-configuration) for more information.

Comment: It should be noted that this is to be used when the version of Spring Boot is lower than 1.4. If it's 1.4 or higher, the other set of properties is to be used(in @Teebo's answer).

Answer (score 34):

With Spring Boot 2.0, you should use this in your application.yml

```
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 100MB
      max-request-size: 100MB
```

From [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-multipart-file-upload-configuration):

> Spring Boot embraces the Servlet 3 `javax.servlet.http.Part` API to support uploading files. By default, Spring Boot configures Spring MVC with a maximum size of **1MB** per file and a maximum of **10MB** of file data in a single request. You may override these values, the location to which intermediate data is stored (for example, to the `/tmp` directory), and the threshold past which data is flushed to disk by using the properties exposed in the `MultipartProperties` class. For example, if you want to specify that files be unlimited, set the **spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size** property to `-1`.

Extracted from [Appendix A of documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

> **spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=1MB** # Max file size. Values can use the suffixes "MB" or "KB" to indicate megabytes or kilobytes, respectively.
>
> **spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB** # Max request size. Values can use the suffixes "MB" or "KB" to indicate megabytes or kilobytes, respectively.

Answer (score 26):

With spring-boot 1.5.3 you should use the following code in application.yml

```
spring:
 http:
  multipart:
   max-file-size: 100MB
   max-request-size: 100MB
```

Make sure to use spaces and not tab in your yaml file.

Answer (score 25):

For setting custom limits for multipart uploads, the below properties are to be used(for a sample size of 30MB):

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=30MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=30MB
```

In our company's projects, I found that one of them was on Spring Boot version 1.3.5, so for versions < 1.4 you should use

```
multipart.max-file-size=30MB
multipart.max-request-size=30MB
```

From the [docs(v1.4.0)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-multipart-file-upload-configuration):

> Spring Boot embraces the Servlet 3 `javax.servlet.http.Part` API to
>   support uploading files. By default Spring Boot configures Spring MVC
>   with a maximum file of 1MB per file and a maximum of 10MB of file data
>   in a single request. You may override these values, as well as the
>   location to which intermediate data is stored (e.g., to the `/tmp`
>   directory) and the threshold past which data is flushed to disk by
>   using the properties exposed in the `MultipartProperties` class. If you
>   want to specify that files be unlimited, for example, set the
>   `spring.http.multipart.max-file-size` property to `-1`.
>
> The multipart support is helpful when you want to receive multipart
>   encoded file data as a `@RequestParam`-annotated parameter of type
>   `MultipartFile` in a Spring MVC controller handler method.

Same docs for version 1.3.8:

> If you want to specify that files be unlimited, for example, set the
>   `multipart.maxFileSize` property to `-1`.

Answer (score 12):

For Spring Boot v2+ add the following to the application.properties:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=40MB
```

Comment: Depends on the spring boot version, see other answer

Comment: for spring-boot version 2+

Answer (score 4):

Application property is one option.  Another option is

```
@Bean
public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
  MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
  factory.setMaxFileSize("10MB");
  factory.setMaxRequestSize("10MB");
  return factory.createMultipartConfig();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On deployment, where the values are inserted via jenkins script, no "-" is allowed. Use:

```
env:
  - name: SPRING_SERVLET_MULTIPART_MAXREQUESTSIZE
    value: "10MB"
  - name: SPRING_SERVLE
    value: "10MB"
```