# Two controllers have different max file size in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-boot

In Servlet 3.0 specification, two servlets have different max file size can be created and worked fine.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/ureupload1" })
// 10MB
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10)
public class UploadServlet1 extends HttpServlet {
```

and

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/ureupload2" })
// 30MB
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 30)
public class UploadServlet2 extends HttpServlet {
```

---

If using Spring Boot Controller, `@MultipartConfig` seems to be not worked.

```
@Controller
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10)
public class UploadController1 {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload1", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public ModelAndView doPost(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
```

How do I create two controllers have different max file size?

EDIT:

Additional information: The following properties are in `application.properties` in order to set default max file size:

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=30MB
```

See also: [SpringBoot's @MultipartConfig maxFileSize not taking effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36945482/springboots-multipartconfig-maxfilesize-not-taking-effect)

Comment: Did you created `StandardServletMultipartResolver` bean

Comment: Or you can also create a `MultipartResolver` bean

Comment: No, I didn't. Can `MultipartResolver` resolve this problem?

Comment: I have tried your code in my system . it works fine .. there is no need to create bean .. did you got any exception

Comment: How you are hitting your API and what content type are you setting ?

Comment: I tried uploading a 20MB file to the above `UploadController1` (maxFileSize=10MB) but it was able to do.

Comment: Ok . let me try this in my system and tell you the result in couple of minutes

Comment: I was able to upload 2 MB image but unable to upload 2 MB zip file. i have set 10 MB size in `maxFileSize` .. what file format are you uploading

Comment: I tried uploading zip file.

Comment: I have tried in my system only this thing work .. i will provide my answer below in a couple of minutes

Comment: I was able to upload my 2 MB zip file after adding this configuartion. @MultipartConfig is not working well with spring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a default configuration in application.properties file

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=30MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=30MB
```

And in your controller you need to throw `MaxUploadSizeExceededException` exception based on the file size :

```
long  limit = 1024 * 1024 * 10; 
if (file.getSize() > limit) {
    throw new MaxUploadSizeExceededException(limit);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. I will vote +1 and close this question, but what I really want to know is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653571/two-controllers-have-different-max-file-size-2mb-and-infinite-in-spring-boot