# Two controllers have different max file size (2MB and infinite) in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-boot

In Servlet 3.0 specification, two servlets have different max file size (for example, 2MB and infinite) can be created and worked fine.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/ureupload1" })
// 2MB
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 2)
public class UploadServlet1 extends HttpServlet {
```

and

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/ureupload2" })
// infinite (or very large size)
@MultipartConfig
public class UploadServlet2 extends HttpServlet {
```

---

If using Spring Boot Controller, `@MultipartConfig` seems to be not worked.

```
@Controller
// 2MB
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 2)
public class UploadController1 {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload1", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public ModelAndView doPost(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
```

How do I create two controllers have different max file size?

Additional information: The following properties are in `application.properties` in order to set default max file size:

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=-1
```

However, I also want to **avoid uploading a large file to `UploadController1` before the file is created** in my server.

See also: [Two controllers have different max file size in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639042/two-controllers-have-different-max-file-size-in-spring-boot) (this is my previous question)

EDIT (additional information):

The solution for my previous question is:

```
long  limit = 1024 * 1024 * 10; 
if (file.getSize() > limit) {
    throw new MaxUploadSizeExceededException(limit);
}
```

However, this is too late to check the file size because the file has already created in my server.

Comment: This is my question and not a duplicate.

Comment: I don't see how that other question is different from this one: you have the same code, and the same problem description (with some minor additions). If this really is a different question, you need to make clear how it is different from your original one. So if this is really a different question, edit it, and explain how this is a follow up instead of just a repeat of your other question.